# Direct Oracle Access cuts off the end of unicode (wide) strings

Tags: string, oracle, delphi, unicode, delphi-xe2

I am encountering a problem with unicode (wide) string field in Delphi XE2 is not returning last part of string and any database control component also is not showing whole string completely to the end.

You can see the simple test below.

```
with TOracleDataSet.Create(self) do
try
  Session := OraSession;
  SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE test1 (fsString10 VARCHAR2(10))';
  ExecSQL;
  SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO test1 (fsString10) VALUES ('''1234567890''')';
  ExecSQL;
  SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO test1 (fsString10) VALUES ('''й234567890''')';
  ExecSQL;
  SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO test1 (fsString10) VALUES ('''йцукенгшщз''')';
  ExecSQL;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT fsString10 FROM test1';
  Open;
  while not Eof do
    ShowMessage(FieldByName('fsString10').AsString); 
    // '1234567890' turned into '1234567890' 
    // 'й234567890' turned into 'й23456789'
    // 'йцукенгшщз' turned into 'йцуке'
  SQL.Text := 'DROP TABLE test1';
  ExecSQL;
finally
  Free;
end;
```

As you can see unicode strings is not properly loaded.

On the other hand the "Direct Oracle Access 4.1.3" component didn't save chars in the string after half one on post record. Anyway it saves only first half-string.

Is there a way to fix it?

- BytesPerCharacter is set to bcAutoDetect.
- I have tried toggling NoUnicodeSupport and all other options with no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

PS: I cannot make changes in production database schema for many reasons.

```
DB Server NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS NLS_CHARACTERSET = CL8MSWIN1251
DB Client NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
DB Client NLS_LANG=RUSSIAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251 <- the same thing
```

Comment: In your debugging, have you determined whether this is a problem with insertion or selection?

Comment: Which character set is configured on your database ? Have you tried your example with `NVARCHAR2` data type ?

Comment: @Rob, problem actually is string buffer size.

Comment: @TLama, NLS_CHARACTERSET = CL8MSWIN1251 but client is unicode. Database fields are very hard to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another one solution without any source code changes.

Simply change oracle client NLS_LANG parameter from

```
AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
```

to

```
AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
```

and set params explicitly on mainform create event:

```
Windows.SetEnvironmentVariable(PChar('NLS_LANG'),
                               PChar('AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251'));
Oracle.NoUnicodeSupport := True;
```

Actually if application is using TWideStringField explicitly, it needs to turn into TStringField.

Answer (score 2):

What is your database character set (from `v$nls_parameters`)?  Have you set a non-default `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` for the database or in the session before you created the table?

Assuming that your database character set supports Unicode (i.e. it is AL32UTF8) and that you are using the default `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`, a `VARCHAR2(10)` allocates up to 10 bytes of storage.  Since AL32UTF8 is a variable-width character set, one character will require between 1 and 3 bytes of storage.  If you are declaring your column in terms of bytes, that means that your column will be able to store between 3 and 10 characters depending on the specific characters you store.  That appears to be consistent with the behavior you are seeing.

The best approach is generally to declare your columns using character length semantics.  If you declare your table

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (fsString10 VARCHAR2(10 CHAR))
```

you'll allow up to 10 characters regardless of the number of bytes that would require.  That appears to be the behavior that you want.

You can change the default length semantics at a session level by setting `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` before you issue your DDL.  If you run

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_length_semantics = CHAR;

CREATE TABLE test1 (fsString10 VARCHAR2(10));
```

your column will also use character length semantics (allocating space for up to 10 characters rather than up to 10 bytes).

It is possible to set `nls_length_semantics` at the system level as well.  However, the Oracle globalization folks generally discourage that because various scripts (Oracle and third-party) are either not tested in that configuration or are known to have problems.

If you don't want to use character length semantics, you can also triple the size of the column in bytes.  That would allow your application to store all three strings.  But that would mean that you could store a 30 character string if it was only comprised of English characters.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. You are right, nls_length_semantics is equal byte. But I cannot make changes of all fields in database schema for many reasons and for me it is not better solution.

Comment: I have run the test with changed create table schema according your approach but the result was the same as shown above.